# how to use my imported xml in my objective-c project?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, datasource, nsxmlparser

i have this demo xml file:

```
<trains>
    <israel>
        <Lehavim>
            <lat>31.370201</lat>
            <lon>34.798336</lon>
        </Lehavim>
        <tel-aviv>
            <lat>32.073847</lat>
            <lon>34.793358</lon>
        </tel-aviv>
    </israel>
</trains>
```

loaded to my project using this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.amotech.co/trains.xml"];
    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [xmlParser setDelegate:self];
    BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];

    if(success)
        NSLog(@"success");
    else
        NSLog(@"Error");
}
```

i need to get my xml into a UITableView - i want to only to show the name of the train station (for example: "Lehavim" in the TableView.

and after i chose one of my table view items - i want to load the current lat and lon data into double objects.

i would like you to help me with this please.
thanks, amir.

Comment: what doesn't work here ? did you run into problems with populating the table view ?

Comment: Hi Amir.  It looks like you've got a handle on the parsing aspect.  You'll essentially be adding the values you want into some array or array of custom objects and then using that as the data source for your UITableView.  Exactly what are you having trouble with, starting from the point of invoking the parse method?

Comment: Hi, i don't really know how to add it into an array.. i've learned it long time ago... /: i believe after i'll add it into an array i will need help how to continue with it.. step by step.. :) THANKS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to get the fundamentals first:

[This link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) takes you to the gory details of NSXMLParser directly from apple.

[This link](http://wiki.cs.unh.edu/wiki/index.php/Parsing_XML_data_with_NSXMLParser) shows a fantastic example of how to use the NSXMLParser.

[This link](http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/08/26/objective-c-tutorial-nsarray/) offers some simple examples for adding objects to an array.

[This link](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/10/uitableview-tutorial/) is a very nice tutorial on UITableViewController.

You will need to provide a little elbow grease.

**Quite Tip**

To save yourself some headaches and to add flexibility to your xml, I recommend you modify your xml structure such that you aren't using your element names as values.

Change:

```
<trains>
    <israel>
        <Lehavim>
            <lat>31.370201</lat>
            <lon>34.798336</lon>
        </Lehavim>
        <tel-aviv>
            <lat>32.073847</lat>
            <lon>34.793358</lon>
        </tel-aviv>
    </israel>
</trains>
```

to:

```
<trains>
    <train>
       <name>israel</name>
       <location>
           <name>Lehavim</name>
           <lat>31.370201</lat>
           <lon>34.798336</lon>
       </location>
       <location>
           <name>tel-aviv</name>
           <lat>32.073847</lat>
           <lon>34.793358</lon>
       </location>
    </train>
</trains>
```

Comment: first of all thank you very much, I'm learning from your links. and its very helpful. i will let you know how its going. thanks again..